# Como baixar um arquivo de um repositório privado do Github?

Tags: javascript, github, private

Oi! Tudo bem?

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto em JavaScript e queria criar um pequeno banco de imagens para ele no Github.
Mas queria deixar privado, só que não sei como posso pegar a URL de uma imagem quando o repo está privado.
Já tentei com o username:password mas nd... Talvez seja pelo Token, mas também não aprendi a mexer com ele.

Se alguém souber, me ajudaria muito!
Ou se alguém tiver uma sugestão de outro sistema que possa fazer usando JS, também aceito.

Obs: Seria muitas imagens, então colocar-las na pasta do projeto e hospedar tudo, seria meio inviável.

Comment: Deve ser mais fácil jogar num volume S3 da Amazon AWS configurado para acesso público.

Comment: Seria para usar em produção? O problema aí é que a chave ficaria aberta no seu js... por isso a ideia acima de usar um volume ou colocar em um CDN é mais viável

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente esse **exemplo:** baixar o arquivo `baz` da versão `0.1.3` de um repositorio privado do Github para o pasta `/tmp`, você faria o seguinte:

```
GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN="seu token"
fetch --repo="https://github.com/usuario/teste" --tag="0.1.3" --source-path="/baz" /tmp
```

Espero que ajude.